# Why even just "delete" asks if the files to be permanently deleted or not?

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, dell, delete

It's a very strange bug, so please read the whole question once before judging it as a duplicate, I couldn't find a question that asks the same thing!

I have Ubuntu 18.04 on Dell Inspiron 14 5000 2-in-1 (without touchscreen part of course, as I couldn't manage that!). I fought a lot to install Ubuntu on this though, but finally, most of the things work, like audio, video, etc. But, a few basic things are strange, for example: if I press "`delete`" it shows this warning

[image]

Somewhere I read that changing the `behavior` under `nautilus preferences` would help, it didn't! Here's the screenshot of the `behavior` tab

[image]

I tried selecting `show action to permanently...` and un-selecting! Both produce the same result! And I also tried restarting nautilus after making those changes in the `behavior`, nothing worked! Always the same message. How can I get a normal `delete` behavior back, where it just deletes something and that ends up in the trash?

NOTE: I remember a few days ago, I could just `delete` something without any warning messages, but those files were also getting permanently deleted skipping the trash, that was even worse! I don't know what has changed since then, but it's also not a great situation either! Please help.

Comment: Are you sure you're not holding down the shift key as you press delete, because that's the exact behavior you are seeing.

Comment: This will also happen if you delete files from file systems that do not support the trash function, such as attached network drives.

Comment: No, I am not hodling ``shift``, I do that to permanently delete a file. But that's exactly how my system is behaving @ubfan1. @vanadium, any file in any location I try to delete, this is what I see.

Comment: :-( so nobody really cares...too rare of an issue maybe!